# Remove item after successful JQuery Sortable action

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, mouseevent, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to create a toolbar for my Java EE application. This toolbar contains icon, which can be dragged to a JQuery Sortable list (DIV columns on a JSP page). My ultimate goal is to show a JSP form after releasing the mouse button.
In the current situation my columns with graphs will contain an icon after a successful drag action, something I do not want.

My question: How can I remove an item, immediately after releasing the mouse button, or to prevent the drop in the first place?

The reason I am using a draggable or sortable action, is that I want to know where the user wants to place the new widget (and save this position).

Hopefully someone can help me/show an example

Answer (score 2):

Well I dont know why you want to remove the item, but reading the jQuery API Documentation would answer your Question. Have you tried something?

**Draggable**

```
$("yourSelector").draggable({
     drop : function() {
            $(this).remove(); 
            // Removes this item from the DOM after a succesful drop
      }
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

**Sortable**

```
$("yourSelector").sortable({
     change : function() {
            $(this).remove(); 
            // Removes this item from the DOM after a change in the sort order
      }
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this, but it doesn't work. The item is still added to the sortable list (I'm using draggable for the drag action). What does work is adding droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) { ui.draggable.remove();} to the sortable list. However, this means that the items in the sortable list will also be removed after a sort action. Not something I want. Is there another option?

Comment: There are many options. But it would really help if you could provide some code snippets you used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come with a solution, based on the answer you gave

```
$(".sortableList").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
       if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("widget")) {
           ui.draggable.remove();
       }
 }
});
```

Maybe not the nicest solution, but it works. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: nice to hear my answer helps you. But an advice for your next question. With some code snippets out of your project you would get a much more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> l$("yourSelector").sortable({
>     change : function() {
>            $(this).remove(); 
>            // Removes this item from the DOM after a change in the sort order
>      }
> });
> ```

@godesign , this does not work for several reasons.

1. the change event is fired **during** sorting, every time the placeholder changes place. The event you search is stop, beforeStop or Update (same as stop, but only when place changed in comparison to original)
2. `$(this)` will not give the sorted item but some unusable jqueryui stuff. You need to get `ui` from parameters and change the function heading to `function(event, ui){`.
3. haven't figured out this part, but altough ui.item is the item you are looking for to delete, ui.item.remove() does not remove this item. **EDIT:** i found that if you do ui.remove() in the `deactivate` event that everything gets deleted fine

the solutions for 1 and 2 are given, the solution for 3 i have not found myself yet.